# Function that converges to zero but can be stretched

Tags: integration, optimization, least-squares

To implement a Recursive Least Squares algorithm I am looking for a function with the shape:
$$
y(x,t)= x + \omega _{1}*f_{1}(x,t) + \omega _{2}*f_{2}(x,t) ... + \omega _{n}*f_{n}(x,t)
$$
Each function is weighted by a factor I seek to optimize. The shape of the graph should start at value "x" for t=0 and converge towards zero over time, however I want to influence and optimize how fast the function converges. One obvious example to show what I mean would be:
$$
y(t)= x - \omega _{0}*t
$$
With a higher weight-factor this function decreases faster over time and with a weight factor close to zero it takes longer. But obviously this function does not converge towards zero. So that's what I am looking for.

Additionally, at the end I want to integrate the terms, which caused me to get stuck when I tried something like:
$$
y(x,t)= x -min(x,t)
$$
[The integral is supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbmAl.png)

It feels like the solution shouldn't be that hard but I just cannot find it. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about $xe^{-kt}$ and adjust $k$ for speed of decay.

Comment: That's actually what I did before I was optimizing using a RLS algorithm. The issue is that I couldn't bring it in the needed shape beside using a Taylor series. Which worked for small time windows but went rogue if a new much longer time window was used.
So far I can't see how to optimize  the k (using the RLS) with that function.

Comment: For now I continue using the Taylor approximation and added a constraint on the maximum value of t. So the the parameters should not exceed what it was trained with. 

Looks decent, but I wish there was a more direct approach . While it works, it isn't really elegant. It's also hard for me to argue that this Taylor approximation doesn't do some weird stuff that a more well-picked function wouldn't do.